# A comfortable BCI device to send mouse clicks all day long

Tags: mice, brain-computer-interface

I am looking for a comfortable BCI (brain-computer interface) device to send mouse clicks for prolonged periods of time (i.e. ~all day long). I tried the NeuroSky's MindWave and the Emotiv EPOC neuroheadset, but they both are quite uncomfortable: wearing them more than one hour is a pain.  It should be compatible with Microsoft Windows and if possible Linux.

Comment: If it's only clicks, perhaps something that register eye blink instead?

Comment: @qarma Thanks, indeed that's another way (that's actually why I used for https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/neuroclick), I'll create a question for visual detection or facial muscle tracking for eye blinks a bit later.